# Multiple ID SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Let's just say I have two tables.

The first one :

```
id thing1 thing2
```

The second :

```
id_fo other_thing
```

where id_fo depend from the first one table.

I have to insert thingS in both table, but in php mysql request (pdo for example), how can I get all last insert id ?

I mean, if I had 30 row in one query, I will have 30 new id.

How can I do my second SQL query ?

Comment: You need to be more explicit... You might want to reformulate the question or give an example of what you need...

Comment: Can't be more explicit than this. If I add 30 rows in the first table, How can i Get all id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Psuedo code:

```
Start transaction
  insert into table1 (thing1, thing2) values (thingS,thingS2)
  lastidtable1 = lastinsertedid();
  insert into table2 (id_fo, other_thing) values (lastidtable1,thingS);
  lastidtable2 = lastinsertedId();
commit;
```

Every of the above lines should php code which calls a query.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
   $main_data = array('dino', 'babu', 'john');

    foreach($main_data as $main) {

      // Insert main to 1st table
      mysql_query("MY INSERT QUERY TO TABLE 1");

      // Get the last insert id
      $new_id = mysql_insert_id();

      // Insert the sub data to 2nd table using the insert id
      mysql_query("MY INSERT QUERY TO TABLE 2 USING $new_id ");
    }
```

Comment: Well, this kind of request is just painfull as soon as you need ton insert many query at once. Imagine something like this INSERT INTO table (thing1,thing2) VALUES ('test','test'),('test2','test2'). But why not after all

Comment: so u need insert ids as an array or something.. ???

Answer (score 0):

INSERT and UPDATE do not return any datasets,you can add an INSERTED column with timestamp type,set DEFAULT to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and select all rows with the greatest timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

if you can guarantee that there is only one insert process going on at a time you could do something like this psuedo code:

```
$max1=select max(id) as max1 from table;
insert into table ....
$num_inserted_rows=number of inserted rows.
$max2=select max(id) as max2 from table;
if(($max2-$max1) == $num_inserted_rows){
    $lastid=select last_insert_id();
    $inserted_ids=range($lastid-$num_inserted_rows,$lastid);
}
```